# PHP Regular Expression - Extract Data

Tags: php, regex

I have a long string, and am trying to extract specific data that is deliminated in that string by specific words.

For example, here is a subset of the string:

```
Current   Owner  123 Capital    Calculated
```

I am looking to extract

```
123 Capital
```

and as you can see it is surrounded by "Current Owner" (with a bunch of arbitrary spaces) to the left and "Calculated" (again with arbitrary spaces) to the right.

I tried this, but I'm a bit new at RegEx.  Can anyone help me create a more effective RegEx?

```
preg_match("/Owner[.+]Calculated/",$inputString,$owner);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I see that the spaces aren't showing in my example, but please note that there can be spaces between the word Current and Owner as well as after the word Owner or before the word Calculated... it is all very arbitrary how many.

Comment: to get spaces to show, you have to indent with four spaces/tab, or surround with backticks. User nu11p01n73R already did this for you in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A character class defines a set of characters. Saying, "match **one** character specified by the class". Place the dot `.` and quantifier inside of a [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) group instead and enable the `s` modifier which forces the dot to span newlines.

```
preg_match('/Owner(.+?)Calculated/s', $inputString, $owner);
echo trim($owner[1]);
```

**Note:** `+` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) operator, meaning it will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regex to match. Use `+?` instead to prevent greediness meaning "one or more — preferably as few as possible".

Comment: maybe pointing out how ungreedy modifiers work would be useful for the OP!

Comment: IMHO, in PHP .+? is .* (no greedy difference as I tested it)

Comment: @KyleK `.+?` should match any character (except newline) more than once, as few times as possible, while still matching the pattern whereas `.*` should match any character (except newline) 0 or more times. There's a big difference.

Comment: Thanks to all for your help. I tried this, but $owner[1] does not return any value... Any further thoughts? Here is my actual code: preg_match("/Owner(.+?)Calculated/",$inputString,$current_owner);
echo "Current Owner: ". trim($current_owner[1]);

Comment: Yes, the s modifier worked.  I modified the Regex to "/Current(.+?)Owner(.+?)Calculated/s" since owner appears a few times, and I needed to limit to Current Owner. I do have one question now though... it returned an array with three values: Array ( [0] => Current   Owner  123 CAPITAL    Calculated [1] =>   [2] =>  123 CAPITAL     ) ...  is there a better way to only get 123 Capital?  Since depending on the data parsed, I need to know which key to choose otherwise... Thanks!

Comment: Now it isn't matching anything hwnd.  :(

Comment: /Current.+Owner(.+?)Calculated/s works... Thanks so much to everyone.  I haven't been coding for a few years, but can I just say this made my day.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookarounds as

```
(?<=Owner)\s*.*?(?=\s+Calculated)
```

Example usage

```
$str = "Current Owner 123 Capital Calculated ";
preg_match("/(?<=Owner)\s*.*?(?=\s+Calculated)/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Will give an output

```
Array ( [0] => 123 Capital )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, group index #1 is your target:

`Owner\s+(\d+\s+\w+)\s+Calculated`

You may also want to try a tool like [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) to help you learn/tinker.